# verify create/update/delete successfully executed in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In hibernate how to confirm/verify whether session.save(entity), session.delete(entity) and session.update(entity) operations have been executed successfully w/o making another call to db?

I mean if you delete an entity how  do you confirm its deleted. can it be done w/o making another call to the database?

Comment: If something goes wrong an Exception will be throw

Comment: Once `session.close()` is executed, the changes will be persisted to the DB. What do you mean by verify?

Comment: @Vikdor: I am implementing the interface methods where I have to return true or false based on the success/failure of these operations.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro: API Doesn't say it throws an Exception which needs be caught?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should watch out for `HibernateException`, a sub-class of `RuntimeException` if you want to catch failures of save/update/delete calls with entities on the session object. If the exception is not thrown, then it means the operation is successful.

If you use JPA semantics, then `PersistenceException` is the counter-part of `HibernateException` that you should watch out to handle such failure scenarios.

Comment: can you also tell me, how we can get the id of the created objects w/o making another call to the database? like in sql you can get the id of the created object by RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS.

Comment: You need to call EntityManager#refresh(entity) in case you are using JPA semantics and Session#refresh(entity) in case of Hibernate, after the save/persist/merge/update method calls.

Comment: Important note--if you have extra conditions in your delete statement and a delete does not occur because those are not met, an exception WILL NOT be thrown. You need to check the row count return value from the executeUpdate() call. If it's 0, the delete failed even if there was no exception.

Answer (score 2):

`session.delete,session.save and session.update` methods throws unchecked `HibernateException` on failure.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate exception will be thrown if the specified operation fails.
So, you should have a catch block for HibernateException. If control comes in this block, then you should return false to indicate that the operation is unsuccessful.